# SQL- building parameterized sql queries

Tags: c#, mysql, sql

```
 OracleCommand cmd2 = cn.CreateCommand();
            cmd2.CommandText = @"SELECT name,addr,zip from master_user where username = @0";
            cmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("0", ddlBins.SelectedValue);

            string x = cmd2.CommandText;
```

ddlBins above is a drop down list. 
lets say the value i selected from the drop down list is 12.
After executing the code above the value of string x should be:

> SELECT name,addr,zip from master_user where username = 12

, correct?..

But for some reason I am getting

> SELECT name,addr,zip from master_user where username = @0

Comment: Nothing, did you try to execute your command? It seems that you think that a parameter placeholder is replaced by the actual value when you call AddWithValue. This is not how it works. Both the command text and the parameters collection with the values are passed to the database engine. It is the database engine that knows how and where use the parameters passed

Comment: yes.. thats what I thought. :)

Comment: @Steve thank you. that makes a lot of sense now. thanks for your explanation.